# Deserializing generically typed classes with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have classes that look like this, based on the json being returned by Slack's api:

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public bool ok { get; set; }
    public string error { get; set; }
}

public class PostMessage : Response<PostMessage>
{
    public string ts { get; set; }
    public string channel { get; set; }
    public Message message { get; set; }
}

public class ChannelsHistory : Response<ChannelsHistory>
{
    public string latest { get; set; }
    public List<Message> messages { get; set; }
    public bool has_more { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to write a single method that can bottleneck the call to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`. I don't know too much about the details of the implementation behind that method, but I thought that this would work:

```
internal static Response<T> GetSlackResponse<T>(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters = null)
    {
        Uri slackUri = BuidSlackUri(typeof(T), parameters);
        String jsonResponse = GetJson(slackUri);
        Response<T> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<T>>(jsonResponse);

        if (!response.ok)
        {
            Aesthetic.Catch("The Slack API failed to respond successfully. " + response.error);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Nothing is failing, but not all of the properties I need are being deserialized. For example, a call to GetSlackResponse() will return a Response that has ok set to true, but I won't have access to the Message property of the PostMessage class. I've tried casting (both explicitly and with `as`), to no avail.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, can someone point it out?

Comment: can pls share the code of message class

Comment: public class Message
   {
       public string type { get; set; }
       public string ts { get; set; }
       public string user { get; set; }
       public string text { get; set; }
       public bool? is_starred { get; set; }
       public bool? wibblr { get; set; }
       public string channel { get; set; }

       [JsonConstructor]
       public Message(){ }

       public Message(RtmEvent rtmObj)
       {
           type = rtmObj.type;
           ts = rtmObj.ts;
           user = rtmObj.user;
           text = rtmObj.text;
           channel = rtmObj.channel;
        }
    }

Comment: some of these properties are keywords.  Try adding serialization attributes as non keywords or change the property names.

Comment: Can you give an example? The code compiles, so I'm not sure what "keywords" you are referring to

Comment: I am unable to create an example, since the code is failing at my sandbox with following error: The type or namespace name 'RtmEvent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Why make `Response<T>` generic?  Why not just `Response`?  It doesn't actually use the `T` generic parameter for anything.  Also, can you give a sample of the JSON you want to deserialize?

Comment: @dbc Good call! I knew I was overthinking something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having my various Response class extend a generically typed class was a red herring; it introduced nothing but making the problem more confusing. I only needed the **method** to be generic, not the **type** itself.

Changing the relevant line in  `GetSlackResponse<T>()` method from

```
Response<T> response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<T>>(jsonResponse);
```

to

```
 T response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);
```

fixed everything. Now my various response types only need to extend my base Response class, *and* will be properly deserialized by JSON.NET. There is no need for the response to be a generically typed object.